# Create Crystal Reports with C# and Access database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to use Crystal Reports in my C# application with Access database. i used this code to generate the report.

```
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleCommand("SELECT * FROM Article", con);

        DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter dscmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(Cmd);
        dscmd.Fill(Ds, "Article");

        CrystalReport7 objRpt7 = new CrystalReport7();
        objRpt7.SetDataSource(Ds);
        crystalReportViewer7.ReportSource = objRpt7;
        crystalReportViewer7.Refresh();
        con.Close();
```

But the report is displaying blank, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the Report is linked to another table,
follow [this link](http://www.freelearningdz.info/2016/02/using-crystal-report-in-c-step-by-step.html)  it helps you in creating Crystal Reports.

Comment: Yes the report was not linked properly, thanks for the link